# Cloudwatch alarm not finding the metric

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have two alarms, both are supposed to monitor exactly the same thing. One is done with a expression (created with query insight), other is done with plain values.

With expression:

```
    {
   "AlarmName":"test",
   "StateValue":"ALARM",
   "StateReason":"Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [2.0 (14/04/23 13:43:00)] was greater than the threshold (0.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for OK -> ALARM transition).",
   "EvaluationPeriods":1,
   "DatapointsToAlarm":1,
   "Threshold":0.0,
   "ComparisonOperator":"GreaterThanThreshold",
   "TreatMissingData":"notBreaching",
   "Metrics":[
      {
         "Id":"q1",
         "Expression":"SELECT SUM(myMetric) FROM MyNamespace WHERE label1 = 'value'",
         "Label":"testAlarme",
         "ReturnData":true,
         "Period":300
      }
   ]
}
```

With plain value:

```
    {
   "AlarmName":"test2",
   "StateValue":"OK",
   "StateReason":"Threshold Crossed: no datapoints were received for 1 period and 1 missing datapoint was treated as [NonBreaching]."

   "MetricName":"myMetric",
   "Namespace":"myNamespace
   "Statistic":"Sum",
   "Dimensions":[
      {
         "Name":"label1",
         "Value":"value"
      }
   ],
   "Period":300,
   "EvaluationPeriods":1,
   "Threshold":0.0,
   "ComparisonOperator":"GreaterThanThreshold",
   "TreatMissingData":"notBreaching",

}
```

So in both cases, the alarm monitors the metric "myMetric" out of namespace "myNamespace".
Doing it with an expression works fine, the data is found and alarm trigger. But when doing it with plain values, alarm does not find any data.

What am I missing here ?